# Including a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, dependencies

I am a newbie in developing JavaScript libraries. I've a basic doubt on how to include a `js` file into another `js` file that is dependent on the former. For example, I'm building a javascript library that replicates the class structures present in the Server code.There are cases for example, where class `B` is contained in class `A`. I want to make a seperate js file to denote class `B` and then include this in the definition of class `A`. How do I go about this ?

I appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends how you're serving your JS.  Consider using Browserify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function in b.js which returns B class (function) and call it inside class A

```
b.js
getClassB function (){
    //define your B class here and return it at the end
    return B;
}

a.js
class/function A(){
    var B = getClassB();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in html page, simply import class A file first and then class B file like

```
<script src="path_to_class_a_file"></script>
<script src="path_to_class_b_file"></script>
```

Comment: ljaz : Thanks! But I want to import class just class A in my HTML page and want the visibility of code of class Bcontained within class A. Also I want to use the class structure of class B in the implementation of class A!